# Not getting all tags for specific class element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to figure out why I'm not getting what I'm intending.  Here is my code below:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.espn.com/college-football/team/schedule/_/id/2132').read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    date_list = []
    for table in soup.find("div", {"class": "mod-content"}):
        for game in table.find_all("tr", {"class": ["oddrow", "evenrow"]}):
            for date in game.find('td'):
                date_list.append(date)
            for opponent in game.find_all("ul", {"class": "game-schedule"}):
                print(opponent)
```

Looking at the source code, there are actually two `<ul class="game-schedule">` in the soup at the same level (siblings??).  When I run the above code, it seems I'm only entering the 1st and retrieving the data from that 1st element only.  I also need to enter the send one to parse that element as well.  I was thinking the `find_all` finds every element specified.  What would I need to do to also enter the 2nd `<ul class="game-schedule">` element??

I want to do something like:

```
for opponent in game.find_all(1ST GAME-SCHEDULE):
    DO STUFF IN FIRST GAME-SCHEDULE
for result in game.find_all(2ND GAME-SCHEDULE):
    DO STUFF IN SECOND GAME-SCHEDULE
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm an idiot.  I had the wrong URL in the source variable.  So I was looking at one page in the browser but trying to scrap another in BS.  Duh!